# Determining the number of integers with a certain amount of factors between two numbers

Tags: python, function, number-theory

I would like to implement a function that takes as input three arguments (x, low, high) - all integers, and finds the number of integers that have `x`  factors between `low` and `high`. For example, how many integers between 50 and 100 have 4 factors?

My code is as follows:

```
def n_factors(x, lower, upper):
""" Find how many integers have x (user-specified)
    factors from - lower to upper - (user-specified) """
    int_counter = 0 # integer counter
    div_count = 0 # divisor counter 
    for i in range(lower, upper+1):
        for j in range(2, i):
            if (i%j)==0:
                div_count += 1
        if (div_count == x):
            print i
            int_counter += 1
     return int_counter
```

When I try to run this I get incorrect results, e.g.

```
n_factors(2,10,20)
10
11
2
```

This should list the four prime numbers between 10 and 20 if 
the function worked but doesn't. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: How is 10 in the output? 10 has 4 factors, namely 1,2,5,10. Do you mean `at least 2 factors`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I'm not sure, the function is not doing what I want it to do

Comment: What is the desired output for `n_factors(2,10,20)`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I mean exactly 2 factors, i.e. prime numbers in this case. But I would like the function to be general to any amount of factors between any two integers

Comment: Do you want the factors to be prime, or just any factors? For example, do you expect n_factors(4, 10, 20) to count 12, since {2, 3, 4, 6} are its factors (excluding 1 and itself, 12)?

Comment: @DonaldV: not just prime, that was just an example I used to validate my function. I would expect n_factors(4,10,20) not to output 12 since it has six factors (yes I am counting 12 and 1).

Comment: So why is j running from 2 to i - 1? Why not from 1 to i? Please explain exactly what you need, then I could tell you what you got wrong.

Comment: @Donald: You are right! Well spotted, I was looping through j incorrectly - it has to be from 1 to  i+1 . I've fixed it now, thanks for your help. Answer posted below

Comment: @Donald: Thanks also for noticing the div_count error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `div_count` back to zero at the end of each iteration:

```
def n_factors(x, lower, upper):
    int_counter = 0 # integer counter
    div_count = 0 # divisor counter
    for i in range(lower, upper+1):
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
            if (i%j)==0:
                div_count += 1
        if div_count == x:
            print i
            int_counter += 1
        div_count = 0
    return int_counter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def n_factors(x, lower, upper):
    facs = {}
    for f in range(1, int(upper**0.5)+1):
        for n in range(lower+f-(lower%f), upper+1, f):
            if n not in facs: facs[n] = []
            facs[n].append(f)

    for n, numFacs in facs.items():
        if len(numFacs) != x: continue
        print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def n_factors(x, lower, upper):
""" Find how many integers have x (user-specified)
    factors from - lower to upper - (user-specified) """
    int_counter = 0
    div_count = 0
    for i in range(lower, upper+1):
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            if (i%j)==0:
                div_count += 1
        if (div_count == x):
            print i
            int_counter += 1
        div_count = 0 
    return int_counter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid errors like this easily by coding at a slightly higher level.

When you need to count "how many times does this condition happen", you don't need to set up a manual counter and forget to reset it - you can translate that sentence quite directly into Python; here the condition is "`j` divides `i` without remainder":

```
for i in range(lower, upper+1):
    div_count = sum(i%j == 0 for j in range(1,i+1))
```

Comment: @Ivc: Thanks for the tip. Is the code faster if I use a generator within the for loop like you have?